# Kafka connect failing to create Mongo Source Connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect

I'm getting an error while creating a source connector. It works fine in all the environments except one place. I'm using a mongodb user having read-write permission which has all the actions changeStream and find. But still I'm getting this error. Also this is not present in `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate` though.

**Config:**

```
{
    "name": "mongo-source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
        "pipeline": "{{pipeline}}", //variable replaced appropriate value
        "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "{{topic}}", //variable replaced appropriate value
        "topic.prefix": "",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "poll.await.time.ms": 5,
        "connection.uri": "${file:/secrets/secrets.properties:mongo.connection.uri}",
        "transforms": "dropPrefix",
        "change.stream.full.document": "updateLookup",
        "errors.tolerance": "none",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.regex": ".*",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter"
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
{
    "error_code": 400,
    "message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nInvalid user permissions. Missing the following action permissions: changeStream, find\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to try /connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate with config value in data:

```
{
        "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
        "pipeline": "{{pipeline}}", //variable replaced appropriate value
        "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "{{topic}}", //variable replaced appropriate value
        "topic.prefix": "",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "poll.await.time.ms": 5,
        "connection.uri": "${file:/secrets/secrets.properties:mongo.connection.uri}",
        "transforms": "dropPrefix",
        "change.stream.full.document": "updateLookup",
        "errors.tolerance": "none",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.regex": ".*",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter"
}
```

P.S.: At least you need a field "name" inside config value.